# Width of certain elements exceed the explorer window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've been having trouble to figure out the solution for this problem.

First, take a look at this [page](http://sharehomme.com/)

This is built in a responsive design, so when you make the window smaller, everything fits to the window. Except, the tags on the right seem to *exceed* the size of the window.
Also, if you compare the padding of the top nav bar, the amount of padding on the left and right is different when it should remain the same.

I'm working on firefox and chrome at the same time to debug this issue. The CSS that governs the top bar is

```
.fixed_pos {
    position: fixed;
    width: 85%;
}
```

and padding on the body from *application.css*

```
body {  
    padding-right: 100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Width is set to 85% because when I set it to 100%, the nav bar exceeds the window size as well (even after I got rid of all the body padding). I want the navbar AND the tags to nicely fit the window instead of exceeding the window width, but I cant seem to get it work.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: If you really look at all of the elements, nothing is centered. Your left and right element margin and width calculations are all over the place. Are you using a specific responsive CSS approach? It doesn't look like Bootstrap per se. But it looks like you may be using a grid, maybe 960 or something? If you haven't seen it, try http://www.initializr.com/

Comment: Also, if you really want to do responsive and modern layout, don't use `table`s for layout. That's just a given.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I'm using Bootstrap and may be not doing things properly enough. Would you be able to chat with me for a few minutes to get things right if possible?

Comment: Sure. I'm going to run and get some dinner here in a minute, but I should be back in 30-45 minutes. Do you have rep to create a chat room?

Comment: @JaredFarrish, Thanks! I'll talk to you then. I'm not sure because I haven't tried to create a chat room yet...

Comment: I'm back if you want to chat.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Hey! how do I start the chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21793/discussion-between-jared-farrish-and-maximus-s)

Answer (score 0):

You defined padding (100px) on body, and then you define a width of 100% on your fixed_pos, with a fixed position. So your div have a size of 100% of the window, starting at position (100,0). That's why it's exceed the window.

If you want to define 100% of the remaining width, you have to declare your position attribute to stay in the flow, like this for example :

```
.fixed_pos {
    position: static; // or nothing, or relative
    width: 85%;
}
```

Comment: But I set the position to fixed to make the top nav bar to always stay on top of the window. Replacing it with static or relative isn't an option for me.